# How is the Firebase Firestore billing for "where" snapshot listener queries?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine I have a Firestore query like this ([ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection)):

```js
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            cities.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
    });
```

Let this query be retrieving 20 records. And,

> The snapshot handler will receive a new query snapshot every time the query results change (that is, when a document is added, removed, or modified).

So my doubt is if a single record is modified/added/deleted, will I be billed again for the whole number of records received by the snapshot? Or will I be billed only for the changes?

i.e., billed again for 20 records if any one of the record get modified?

Comment: ugh. Frank, I know it - but missed. I'm away from keyboard and just now received an email for your above comment. It'd be nice if SO can email me if someone answer my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `onSnapshot` listener is still active, you will only be charged for the document that was changed as that's the only document that needs to be read from the server. The other documents are already on the client.